# Can I get an alert when my iPhone 5S is unplugged?

Tags: iphone, charge

My iPhone 5S gives a beep or buzz when I plug it in to a charger, but doesn’t provide any notification, apart from the lightning bolt in the top right hand corner disappearing, when it gets unplugged.

I’d like to get such a notification because my phone has a tendency to stop charging if the cable has the slightest touch to it - this happens with many different cables.

My phone is not jailbroken, so https://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/02/23/unpower-jailbreak-tweak/ doesn’t help. I’m on iOS 12.5.1, and according to [Apple security updates](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201222), the iPhone 5S isn't supported for iOS 13 or 14.

Answer (score 4):

You can reach that with the *shortcut*-app by creating an automation:

1. Open Shortcut-App and create a new Automation (click +)
2. Choose "Create Personal Automation"
3. Scroll the page down and select "Charger"
4. Choose "Is Disconnected" and click "Next"

[image]

5. Click button "+ Add Action"
6. Select "Show Notification", findable through the search field
7. Write the show notification as example "Is Disconnected from Power", then "Next"

[image]

8. Deselect "Ask Before Running" if this shortcut should be triggered automatically
9. Click "Done" and your shortcut is finished and executable

[image]

Comment: This is looking good, it'll just take some time to work out whether the version of the "Shortcuts" app I have can do this.

Comment: But why should this "take some time to find out if the version of the *Shortcuts*-app I have can"? Just give it a try, it won't take long...

Comment: On my iPhone 5s (iOS 12.5.1), I can install Shortcuts version 2.2.2. In that version, if I click on the plus sign in the top right hand corner, I get a window that it titled "Untitled Shortcut 1" which tells me how to build a shortcut (like 2:37 of [iOS 12: How to Use Shortcuts!](https://youtu.be/7zze9wbtzjI?t=157), which I assume is different from building an automation. Likewise, when I look at the documentation on the Shortcuts app on [automations](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/shortcuts/apd690170742/ios), it only goes back to version 3.1.

Comment: Shortcut automations are only available on iOS 13 and later.